# $\omega(A_{\beta})\geq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $\beta$ and $\|A_{\beta_0}\|<1$ for some $\beta_0$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

Let the matrix $A_\beta=\begin{pmatrix} \beta & 1+\beta \\ 0 & 2\beta \end{pmatrix}$ with $\beta\in \mathbb{C}$.

> I want to calculate the numerical radius and the operator norm of $A_\beta$. If the calculus of $\|A_{\beta}\|$ and $\omega(A_{\beta})$ is difficult. Is it possible to prove that $\omega(A_{\beta})\geq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $\beta$ and to find some $\beta_0$ such that $\|A_{\beta_0}\|<1$.

The numerical radius of $A_\beta$ is given by
 \begin{align*}
\omega(A_\beta)
&=\sup\left\{\left|\beta|x|^2+(1+\beta)y\overline{x}+2\beta|y|^2\right|\,;\;(x,y)\in \mathbb{C}^2, |x|^2+|y|^2=1 \right\}.
\end{align*}
Clearly, one may observe that for all $(x,y)\in \mathbb{C}^2$ with $|x|^2+|y|^2=1$, we have
$$\left|\beta|x|^2+(1+\beta)y\overline{x}+2\beta|y|^2\right|\leq \tfrac{|\beta|}{2}+2|\beta|.$$
Hence, $\omega(A_\beta)\leq\tfrac{|\beta|}{2}+2|\beta|.$

The operator norm of $A_\beta$ is given by
 \begin{align*}
\|A_\beta\|^2
&=\sup\left\{\left|\beta x+(1+\beta)y\right|^2+4\left|\beta\right|^2\left|y\right|^2\,;\;(x,y)\in \mathbb{C}^2, |x|^2+|y|^2=1 \right\}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the numerical radius.

Let $\beta=a+ib$; then $w(A)=\sqrt{-m/4}$ where $m$ is the $\min$ of the real roots of $pol(l)$, the following polynomial of degree $4$ in the unknown $l$.

[image]

if you are interested, I can give you the details.

Example: when $a=4,b=-7$, we obtain $\omega(A)\approx 17.9883$.

EDIT 1. Answer to the OP. Of course, your conjecture is false. Yet, we can obtain an explicit form for  your numerical radius; indeed, $pol$ can be factorized as follows

$pol=lf_1(l)f_2(l)$ where

[image]

The root of $f_1$ is always $\geq 0$ and, therefore, is not convenient. Thus $m$ is the smallest of the $2$ roots of $f_2$, that is

[image]

EDIT 2. To the OP. As I wrote to you, it's now your job. Use formal calculation software like Maple; if it is too expensive, then you can use Sage for free; it is not very pleasant to use but very efficient.

Here are the results.

$\omega(A)\geq 1/2$ with equality only for $\beta=0$.

${||A||_2}^2=$

[image]

Its minimum is [image]

and is only reached in $\beta=$

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I hope to find explicitely the value of $\omega(A_\beta)$. Is it incorrect that $$\omega(A_\beta)=\tfrac{|\beta|}{2}+2|\beta|?$$

Comment: OK I remove my comment.

Comment: Your edit is very helpful and thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

The question is in two parts, the straight operator norm of $A$ is the largest eigenvalue of $|A|$ modulus of $A$ which has the representation you gave as supremum. The second is trickier for the numerical radius whether  it is known that for $2\times 2$  complex matrices the numerical range   $W$ (the set in the plane) is a known ellipse given the matrix. The numerical radius is the largest number in modulus $\in W$.

(A long comment )

As it's said when the numerical range is determined we have the equation of the ellipse curve, a second degree in terms of $x$ and $y$, now finding the numerical radius  is maximizing a second degree polynomial in $x$ by Pythagoras. Other answers will fruitful also.

Comment: I know the definitions however as I explain in my attempt I'm facing difficulties to find the exact value of the numerical radius

Comment: I would add it was a sort of comment, in calculation there is a formula that defines the ellipse of the numerical range, without it estimating as you did don't give you the true numerical radius.  The formula is known but is not trivial in article of  Prof.Chi Kwong Li, i don't see another way. The operator norm is an eigenvalue, not a direct value as you gave it.

Comment: Maybe there is another way, because i think if you know the set numerical range this ellipse (foci axes) could you find the largest element in modulus? i don't have an answer?

Comment: $\omega(A_{\beta})\ge \frac{1}{2}$ if we take $x=\begin{pmatrix}\pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\\pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\end{pmatrix}$ and evaluating $|x^*A_{\beta}x|^2\ge 0.25$. The operator norm bound isn't true for $\beta=-1$

Comment: Thanks a lot. For the operator norm i want to find some $\beta_0$ and not for all $\beta$.

Comment: $\|A_{\beta}\|_o\ge 1$ for all $\beta\in \mathbb{C}$ may hold.

Comment: I don't think Toni

Comment: It is a certain polynomial in $\beta$ that you need to prove that it is larger than $1$ in modulus, (after you compute the eigenvalues of $A_{\beta}^TA_{\beta}$ and you try to bound -it is another question)

Comment: Thank you but it is not a new question because my goal is the calculate the operator norm. Since this is difficult, I hope to prove that is less than 1 for some $\beta_0$. I will try to solve it. Thanks again.

Comment: you are right i checked that for small negative $\beta$ the operator norm $<1$ for $-0.2$ example. Again the expression of the operator norm (eigenvalues) and also the numerical radius is possible in terms of $\beta$ real and imaginary parts using a formal software